# SQL Syntax error 'LIMIT 0, 10'

Tags: php, sql, web

Hey I have this error when trying to access my website; 
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 10' at line 1"

Line one for me is `<?php require_once('Connections/blog.php'); ?>`

but it seems the error is coming from here;

```
$maxRows_getDisplay = 10;
$pageNum_getDisplay = 0;
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_getDisplay'])) {
  $pageNum_getDisplay = $_GET['pageNum_getDisplay'];
}
$startRow_getDisplay = $pageNum_getDisplay * $maxRows_getDisplay;

mysql_select_db($database_blog, $blog);
$query_getDisplay = "SELECT news.title, news.pre,  
 DATE_FORMAT(news.updated, '%M %e, %Y') AS formatted 
 FROM news ORDER BY news.updated DESC LIMIT 2";
$query_limit_getDisplay = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", 
 $query_getDisplay, $startRow_getDisplay, $maxRows_getDisplay);
$getDisplay = mysql_query($query_limit_getDisplay, $blog) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getDisplay = mysql_fetch_assoc($getDisplay);
```

If you have any idea, please as I am completely lost.

Comment: `$query_getDisplay` contains a `LIMIT` clause at the end, then on the next line you add another `LIMIT` clause to `$query_limit_getDisplay`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have created an SQL statement with two LIMIT clauses, which is not allowed.

This example shows how difficult it is to debug SQL by staring at the code you use to build up a SQL string.

It's much easier if you can output the *final* SQL string to debug it.

```
$query_getDisplay = "SELECT news.title, news.pre,  
 DATE_FORMAT(news.updated, '%M %e, %Y') AS formatted 
 FROM news ORDER BY news.updated DESC LIMIT 2";
$query_limit_getDisplay = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", 
 $query_getDisplay, $startRow_getDisplay, $maxRows_getDisplay);
error_log("What's wrong with this SQL?  " . $query_limit_getDisplay);
$getDisplay = mysql_query($query_limit_getDisplay, $blog) or die(mysql_error());
```

You'll see in your error log:

```
What's wrong with this SQL?  SELECT news.title, news.pre,  
DATE_FORMAT(news.updated, '%M %e, %Y') AS formatted 
FROM news ORDER BY news.updated DESC LIMIT 2 LIMIT %d, %d
```

And that makes it much easier to spot invalid SQL syntax (assuming you can recognize valid vs. invalid SQL syntax).

Comment: So just get rid of `LIMIT 2`?

Comment: Yes, you can only have one LIMIT clause per SELECT.

Comment: Ah thanks it worked =D
I was following the Adobe 'Create Your First Dynamic Website'